# Target class [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Blog] does not exist

Tags: laravel-8

The first three routes are working fine other routes give the error.

[image]

BlogController.php

[image]

The blade file

[image]

The error

[image]

Comment: You have to check the route and make sure about double `blog/{blog}`

Answer (score 0):

In BlogController you need add

```
use App\Models\Blog;
```

or wherever path Blog